# Swift IAP ensure payments go to DB

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am creating an iOS that does Consumable IAP purchases of points. As we know there is no restore option with consumables. I want to make sure that if user pays that they get their points is saved in DB and vice versa. How would you guard against losing connectivity right in the middle between charging and saving in DB!?

I am trying to avoid using `NSUserDefaults`, just in case the user after purchase, delete the app.

This is the method that gets called when a purchase is successful/failed:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
```

If I delay saving to DB till after this method returns `SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased`, and lose connectivity (not reach my DB), the user will end up paying and points are not awarded.

I must ensure that I charge user and save new user points in DB. they don't have to happen both right away, but some mechanism to check when connectivity is back up.

[image]

Comment: You could use NSUserDefaults as a temp storage area until the data is successfully uploaded to the DB, then remove from NSUD.

Comment: Yes, that was my first stab at it. I didn't like that option for the scenario I mentioned above (user pays and then kills app), while I haven't been able to save to DB due to lack of connection. Another issue is the security reason, I didn't want to give the user the option to see how I am structuring my product identifiers.

Comment: Security doesn't really matter unless you're concerned with jail broken devices. They can't do anything with your product IDs.

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could see about validating receipts [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1), they can be validated with the app store or locally, you'd have to choose the best approach for you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I am already actually using the receipts to verify purchases. The problem with that it doesn't tell me the transaction it will save it under beforehand to allow me to do the cross-reference. It can charge the user and then when I try to read it, network is down! I don't want to use local storage for security reasons per @TheValyreanGroup suggestion.